# How is Linq helping to use a method of List<T> class from IList<T> reference holding List<T> object?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am able to call `ToArray()` method of `List<T>` class from a reference of `IList<T>` interface, just by including the line `using System.Linq`. But without the Linq namespace, the code gave an error saying, "no such method in IList interface".

Using C# with .NET Core.

```
IList<int> l = new List<int>();
...

int[] arr = (int[])l.ToArray(typeof(int));
```

Comment: Linq provides extension methods on IEnumerable<T> - IList<T>detrives from IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a `ToArray()` that takes parameters.

This code :

```
int[] arr =l.ToArray();
int[] arr2 = (int[])l.ToArray();
```

Is equivalent to this :

```
int[] array = Enumerable.ToArray(l);
int[] array2 = Enumerable.ToArray(l);
```

IL code:  intersting part at `IL_0008` and `IL_000f`

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: call !!0[] [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToArray<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
IL_000d: stloc.1
IL_000e: ldloc.0
IL_000f: call !!0[] [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToArray<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
IL_0014: stloc.2
IL_0015: ret
```

Using F1 on it will lead you to the MSDN documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2

Stating that it's within the namespace:
`System.Linq`.

[`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods) only provide the method:

`Add(Object)`,
`Clear()`,
`Contains(Object)`,
`CopyTo(Array, Int32)`,
`GetEnumerator()`  Inherited from `ICollection`,
`IndexOf(Object)` Inherited from `IEnumerable`,
`Insert(Int32, Object)`,
`Remove(Object)`,
`RemoveAt(Int32)`.

---

[SharpLab demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQOgMID2ANkQKYDGALgJYEB2AzmpvEgCzNZI4Ay1dAR2YYoAZgQAmOHjgBvDHEUJxUNnACyACgCUchUoP6DigJJ8GlADz9KAPjhE4AXjh1SAdzjmrN2zuHoxko2ANoAunAAhgBO0c5EOAAqBACCsZEAnv5GxqERMdFSLpp52gnJadGZ2YFBcDkGAPSNpLEEcXgAyogArDCIIHAAcgRwBABurUQEkcBwAGbtcAC2pJQAFgRzAOQV6RnbcJSRANakDHCIUdEA5gCuq3SUDA1KzXnX0eLFpeWp+5pKBkAA6kAjzEpPbTaZgGAC+GDhQA===) to see the intermediate steps and results of code compilation.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments the ToArray() is an extension method useable on an IList in the System.Linq namespace.

The reason IList doesn't have this fuction but List does. Is because the List class has a ToArray() method defined, which IList has not. Which would explain the error on IList.ToArray()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2